# What happens to the data in a TCP socket's send buffer after the client calls close()?

Tags: sockets, tcp

If the client calls the `write()` function to write a large amount of data to the buffer of `socketfd`, and then calls `close(socketfd)`, will the client still send the data remaining in the buffer to the server?

Comment: It will be sent until the peer issues an RST, which will cause a `broken pipe` or `connection reset` at the sender. The peer application will never see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will the client still send the data remaining in the buffer to the server?

*It depends.*

By default, yes.  However, you can disable the behavior using the `SO_LINGER` socket option:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html

> `SO_LINGER`
> Sets or gets the SO_LINGER option.  The argument is a `linger` structure.
>
> ```
> struct linger {
>     int l_onoff;    /* linger active */
>     int l_linger;   /* how many seconds to linger for */
> };
> ```
>
> When enabled, a `close(2)` or `shutdown(2)` will not return until all queued messages for the socket have been successfully sent or the linger timeout has been reached. Otherwise, the call returns immediately and the closing is done in the background.  When the socket is closed as part of `exit(2)`, it always lingers in the background.

This is discussed in more detail on MSDN for Windows (`closesocket()` is Windows' equivalent to `close()` for sockets, but the behavior is similar for Posix systems):

[Graceful Shutdown, Linger Options, and Socket Closure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/graceful-shutdown-linger-options-and-socket-closure-2)

> In Windows Sockets, both the `shutdown` function, and the `WSASendDisconnect` function can be used to initiate a shutdown sequence, while the `closesocket` function is used to deallocate socket handles and free up any associated resources. Some amount of confusion arises, however, from the fact that the `closesocket` function implicitly causes a shutdown sequence to occur if it has not already happened. In fact, it has become a rather common programming practice to rely on this feature and to use `closesocket` to both initiate the shutdown sequence and deallocate the socket handle.
>
> To facilitate this usage, the sockets interface provides for controls by way of the socket option mechanism that allow the programmer to indicate whether the implicit shutdown sequence should be graceful or abortive, and also whether the `closesocket` function should linger (that is not complete immediately) to allow time for a graceful shutdown sequence to complete. These important distinctions and the ramifications of using `closesocket` in this manner are still not widely understood.
>
> By establishing appropriate values for the socket options `SO_LINGER` and `SO_DONTLINGER`, the following types of behavior can be obtained with the `closesocket` function:
>
> - Abortive shutdown sequence, immediate return from `closesocket`.
> - Graceful shutdown, delaying return until either shutdown sequence completes or a specified time interval elapses. If the time interval expires before the graceful shutdown sequence completes, an abortive shutdown sequence occurs, and `closesocket` returns.
> - Graceful shutdown, immediate return—allowing the shutdown sequence to complete in the background. Although **this is the default behavior**, the application has no way of knowing when (or whether) the graceful shutdown sequence actually completes.